# In a Bayesian Framework, can we ever replace nuisance parameters by their MLE?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am wondering if it is permissible in a Bayesian analysis to replace nuisance parameters with their maximum likelihood estimates. I am dealing with a model which commonly has several thousand of these, and it appears to be a stretch for my MCMC implementation.

I would appreciate any research suggestions.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like a use case for ABC or maybe stan.

Comment: Check out empirical Bayes